# Не отображается форма в потоке

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Добрый день всем.
Имеем красивенькую форму прогресса загрузки данных. Открываю в отдельном потоке:

```
Thread ProgressThread= new Thread(delegate ()
        {
            Application.Run(new Frm_progress());

        });
        ProgressThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        ProgressThread.Start();
```

InitializeComponent отрабатывает но форма не отображается(
в чем причина?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71578/discussion-on-question-by------).